# Stuck on this definite integral

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

> I am trying to solve this definite integral
>   $$3\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt {\cos x}}{(\sqrt {\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x})^5} \,dx$$

I take the following approach- I first remove the numerator by using the definite integral property

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x)  dx$$
Using the above property and simplfying

$$\dfrac{3}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \dfrac{sec^2x}{(1+\sqrt {tanx})^4} dx$$
Then I use the substitution $$\tan x=t$$
$$\Rightarrow \sec^2x dx=dt$$
Then I get a new integral 
$$\dfrac{3}{2}\int_0^\infty \dfrac{dt}{(1+\sqrt t)^4}$$
I am stuck now because I do not know how to evaluate limits with infinity. Please help

Answer (score 5):

Better substitution could be

$1+\sqrt{\tan x}=t,\tan x=?$

$$I=3\int\dfrac{2(t-1)dt}{t^4}$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Here is an approach. Substitute $u^2 = t$
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{2u\ du}{(1+u)^4}
$$
and then write
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^\infty \frac{u\ du}{(1+u)^4}
 &= \int_0^\infty \frac{(1+u)\ du}{(1+u)^4}
  - \int_0^\infty \frac{du}{(1+u)^4} \\
 &= \int_0^\infty (1+u)^{-3}du - \int_0^\infty (1+u)^{-4}du
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Representing the integral you left with as $I$ we have after substituting $t=s^2$ that
$$I=3\int_0^{\infty}\frac{s}{(1+s)^4}ds$$

Now note that $$\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}=B(x,y)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^{x-1}}{(1+u)^{x+y}}du$$

Where $B(x,y)$ is the standard Beta function while $\Gamma(z)$ is the Complete Gamma function.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

rewrite $\sin(x)=\frac{\tan(x)}{\sec(x)}$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{\sec(x)}$.

Now, use the substitution $u=\tan(x)$

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I think the OP has done this already.

Comment: Not really, because if you then expand the binomial you get $$\int \frac{1\ du}{(1+u)^4}-\int \frac{1\ du}{(1+u)^5}$$. These two integrals are very straightforward to solve. Regarding the fact that they are improper integrals, it is now just needed to take the limit.

Comment: I do not know improper integral

Comment: @mathdude I see. Well, I think that this integral will always reduce down to either a first kind or a second kind improper integral. The reason is the $\tan(x)$ is not defined at $x=pi/2$.